# Expressing a definite integral as pure function with the upper-bound as it argument

Tags: core-language, pure-function

Suppose i have an integral which has a closed form,

$\quad \quad \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=F(a,b)$

I want to use output function $F$ as a pure function, like `F[a,#]&` so i try the following:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, #}]&;
```

but this does not evaluate the integral before setting it as a pure function. So I tried the following:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a,b}];
(% /. {b -> #})&;
```

but this doesnot evaluate the last result variable %. So I also tried the following to no success:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, #}]
Function[%];
```

In the maple programming language there is a command "unapply" which evaluates the definition of the function before assigning the arrow operator to it. Is there any equivalent to this in *Mathematica*? (I am new to *Mathematica*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how general solution you want but you can do something like:

```
Evaluate[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] /. b -> (#)] &
```

Comment: Thank you that's general enough for me.